# .NET ETW - unintended keywords - SessionN

Tags: .net-4.5, etw

using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.* ETW on .NET 4.5
the end result somehow created additional keywords for all log : Session0, Session1, Session2, Session3

this even happened for ETW library sample codes

known issue?

Comment: how do you capture the events?

Comment: no capturer/listener, just event publisher. practically the same like the library sample code

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with this. I capture the Events via Perfview or WPR.

Comment: i just need the events show up in event viewer, so i don't need other tool for the capturing

Answer (score 0):

http://www.shujaat.net/2013/09/net-45-eventsource-windows-event-log.html?showComment=1410351588387#c5917443851300280552

looks like a known issue

I do can find these funny keywords in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

[image: log in Event Viewer: see the Keywords] [source](http://www.shujaat.net/2013/09/net-45-eventsource-windows-event-log.html)

It's created by `CreateManifestAndDescriptors()` in [eventsource.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/eventing/eventsource.cs,afcf1ed815ca8f4d) (see Line 3346)

```
// Use reflection to look at the attributes of a class, and generate a manifest for it (as UTF8) and
// return the UTF8 bytes.  It also sets up the code:EventData structures needed to dispatch events
// at run time.  'source' is the event source to place the descriptors.  If it is null,
// then the descriptors are not creaed, and just the manifest is generated.  
private static byte[] CreateManifestAndDescriptors(Type eventSourceType, string eventSourceDllName, EventSource source,
    EventManifestOptions flags = EventManifestOptions.None)
{
    ///...
    // ensure we have keywords for the session-filtering reserved bits
    // 
    {
        manifest.AddKeyword("Session3", (long)0x1000 << 32);
        manifest.AddKeyword("Session2", (long)0x2000 << 32);
        manifest.AddKeyword("Session1", (long)0x4000 << 32);
        manifest.AddKeyword("Session0", (long)0x8000 << 32);
    }
//...
}
```